# PHP: Including Files in Scripts Called Out to by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, include

I've done some hunting around, and I haven't seen my question asked by anyone yet. So, I'll ask here.

I'm new to computers in general and very new to web development specifically. I'm currently building my first website. It has a back-end database, server side scripting, the whole shebang.

Also, I'm on a Linux/Apache/PHP platform using a LAMPP local host server.

Preliminaries discussed, I was coding an AJAX call today (my first!) and came across some strange behavior on the front end. I'll post the code, but I'll briefly explain first.

My code is for a log-in form that verifies your password and username and then either lets you move on into the site or puts up an error message on the screen. I use JS for front end error checking just to stop any unnecessary data exchange from the client to the server.

Of course, you can't trust anything on the front end, so I wrote some PHP to error check on the back end as well. To test the efficacy of my back end error checking, I intentionally changed the parameters of the back end code so that my input would be accepted by JS but rejected by PHP.

Here is the code:

```
function serverValidation(x, y){

var z;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){z=new XMLHttpRequest();}

else{z=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

z.onreadystatechange=function(){ 

  if (z.readyState==4 && z.status==200 && z.responseText == "false"){

     $("#submit_error_3").show(); 

     $( "#submit_error_3" ).text("X INVALID ENTRY"); 

     $( "#username, #password").css("border-color", "red");

  }

  if (z.readyState==4 && z.status==200 && z.responseText == "true"){ 

     $("#hidden_form_profile").submit();

  }

}

z.open("POST","login.php",true);

z.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-

urlencoded"); 

z.send("username=" + x + "&" + "password=" + y);

}
```

As you can see, I'm using POST to send form-like data, and I'm receiving ordinary text. The response is either the string "true" or the string "false". If "true" is received, the JS goes one way. If "false" is received, the JS goes another.

Here's the back end:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

  $x = trim($_POST['username']);

  $y = $_POST['password'];

  if(validate($x, $y)){$_SESSION["logged_in"] = "true"; echo "true";}

  else{

     echo "false";

  }

}

function validate($x, $y){

if( strlen($x)  < 6 ||  strlen($y)  < 6 ){ 

  return false;

}

return true;

}

?>
```

This all works great, just as expected.

But, the back end isn't done. Once the format of the input is verified, I then plan on going into the database and matching the username and password to see whether the input is valid.

To that end, I included a PHP file with: `include "login_info.php";` at the very top of the AJAX back-end script. This file just holds basic variables for the database server address, the database name, the username, and password.

Once I included that file, saved, and refreshed, things got VERY strange.

Basically the AJAX call stopped working. Through troubleshooting with alert boxes and such, I ascertained that the PHP script did its job, but the front end script wouldn't interpret the data properly.

As far as the JS was concerned, the returning data was a string and it took on the values "true" and "false" under the expected circumstances, but `if(z.responseText == "false")` and `(z.responseText == "true")`both evaluated to false in all cases.

Further, `if(z.responseText)` always evaluated as true in all cases. That is, when I included that extra file, somehow the JS considered the returning data to be a string with the expected value but treated it as a boolean that was always true.

Can someone explain to me what happened when I included that file in the back-end script?

Comment: I think that is because of the session start

Comment: It should be before any output you need to add the session start

Comment: Try putting the session start at the top most part of the php file.

Comment: here you are setting `$_SESSION["logged_in"] = "true"` or trying to check if its true like `$_SESSION["logged_in"] == "true"`

Comment: The session start is at the top. It works fine with the session start. It's just if I add an include that things get crazy.

Comment: `crazy` is not enough to tell whats wrong and if you have error post with question, if the result is not desired post the output in question along with how you want the output

Comment: I stated what was wrong in the question. I really cant post outputs and desired outputs without putting the code for the whole page up there. Impractical.

Comment: Figured it out. Whitespaces outside the closing tag. Crazy, huh? Why is PHP so whitespace sensitive?